# Sinatra app works on IP but not domain

Tags: ruby, apache, ubuntu, sinatra, passenger

I have installed and deployed a basic Sinatra app via Apache & Passenger with Ruby 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 using these guides:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-sinatra-based-ruby-web-applications-on-ubuntu-13

The Sinatra app works fine when accessing it via IP, but when accessing the site via the domain, I get an index of the folders in the directory on my home location on the server.

My WordPress blog installed on this server is working with the domain, so I don't believe it's a DNS issue.

I have ensured the domain is linked with the IP in /etc/hosts. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set the ServerName in your apache config?

Comment: It's currently set to the IP, but if I set it to the domain, I see no change, except then neither the IP nor the domain work.